# Maximum of x_i + y_j for i>j

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization, data-structures, data-science

Suppose we have two arrays, x_1,...,x_n and y_1,...,y_n. Finding the maximum pairwise sum of the two arrays can be computed in O(n) by first finding the maximum element of both arrays in O(n) and then summing it:

max_{i,j} x_i + y_j = max_i x_i + max_j y_j

However, if we want to find the maximum such that the indices of x_i and y_j are non decreasing, I'm not sure we can do this in less than O(n^2) by enumerating all possibilities.

max_{i>j} x_i + y_j

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in O(n log n) worst case complexity? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will solve your problem, it's an O(n) solution.
We can see $$\max_{i > j} x_i + y_j = \max_{i}  x_i + \max_{i > j} y_j$$

```cpp
int ymax = y[0], res = y[0] + x[1];

for(int i = 1; i < len; ++i){
    res = max(res, ymax + x[i]);
    if(i < ylen) ymax = max(ymax, y[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I also figured it out (see above). I think they are equivalent!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Consider this algorithm:

```
sum_max = -Inf;
y_max = -Inf;

for i in 1:n do
y_max = max(y_max,y_i)
sum_max = max(x_i+y_max,sum_max)

return sum_max
```

The complexity would be O(n) due to n applications of 2 element maximum operations.